# Problem showing video on VideoView

Tags: android, android-video-player

I has this following code to show a VideoView on top of anything that is showing on my screen.

```
public void showVideo(float x, float y) {
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams params = (AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams) video.getLayoutParams();
    params.width=190;
    params.height=240;
    params.x = (int) x;
    params.y = (int) y;

    video.requestLayout();

    video.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("file://sdcard/test-edition/sample.mp4"));
    video.start();
}
```

(Yeah this use AbsoluteLayout, I need show it on top at specific locations (any other solutions for this is appreciated)).

This path to "file://sdcard/test-edition/sample.mp4" is a valid mp4 that I downloaded for tests purpose.

When showing it the system only says "Impossible to play video. A error ocurred.", but there's no stacktrace on Logcat. If it's usefull I has this verbose infos when trying to run it:

```
VERBOSE/MediaPlayer-JNI(824): native_setup                                                                                                                                           
VERBOSE/MediaPlayer(824): constructor                                                                                                                                                
VERBOSE/MediaPlayer(824): setListener                                                                                                                                                
VERBOSE/MediaPlayer-JNI(824): setDataSource: path /test-edition/sample.mp4                                                                                                           
VERBOSE/MediaPlayer(824): setDataSource(/test-edition/sample.mp4)                                                                                                                    
VERBOSE/PVPlayer(2417): PVPlayer constructor                                                                                                                                         
VERBOSE/PVPlayer(2417): construct PlayerDriver                                                                                                                                       
VERBOSE/PlayerDriver(2417): constructor                                                                                                                                              
VERBOSE/PlayerDriver(2417): OpenCore hardware module not found                                                                                                                       
VERBOSE/PlayerDriver(2417): start player thread                                                                                                                                      
VERBOSE/PlayerDriver(2417): startPlayerThread                                                                                                                                        
VERBOSE/PlayerDriver(2417): InitializeForThread                                                                                                                                      
VERBOSE/PlayerDriver(2417): OMX_MasterInit                                                                                                                                           
VERBOSE/PlayerDriver(2417): OsclScheduler::Init                                                                                                                                      
VERBOSE/PlayerDriver(2417): CreatePlayer                                                                                                                                             
DEBUG/(2417): SISO TEST registering PVMFRecognizerPluginFactory                                                                                                                      
DEBUG/(2417): SISO TEST registering PVMFRecognizerPluginFactory success                                                                                                              
VERBOSE/PlayerDriver(2417): AddToScheduler                                                                                                                                           
VERBOSE/PlayerDriver(2417): PendForExec                                                                                                                                              
VERBOSE/PlayerDriver(2417): OsclActiveScheduler::Current                                                                                                                             
VERBOSE/PlayerDriver(2417): StartScheduler                                                                                                                                           
VERBOSE/PVPlayer(2417): send PLAYER_SETUP                                                                                                                                            
VERBOSE/PlayerDriver(2417): Send player code: 2                                                                                                                                      
VERBOSE/PlayerDriver(2417): CommandCompleted                                                                                                                                         
VERBOSE/PlayerDriver(2417): Completed command PLAYER_SETUP status=1                                                                                                                  
VERBOSE/PVPlayer(2417): setDataSource(/test-edition/sample.mp4)                                                                                                                      
INFO/PlayerDriver(2417): PlayerDriver::isProtectedFile(/test-edition/sample.mp4)                                                                                                     
VERBOSE/PlayerDriver(2417): File EXT is : .mp4                                                                                                                                       
ERROR/PlayerDriver(2417): PlayerDriver::it is a not Protected file                                                                                                                   
VERBOSE/MediaPlayer(824): setVideoSurface                                                                                                                                            
VERBOSE/PVPlayer(2417): setVideoSurface(0x6fd00)                                                                                                                                     
VERBOSE/MediaPlayer-JNI(824): setAudioStreamType: 3                                                                                                                                  
VERBOSE/MediaPlayer(824): MediaPlayer::setAudioStreamType                                                                                                                            
VERBOSE/MediaPlayer-JNI(824): prepareAsync: surface=0x2cae40 (id=2)                                                                                                                  
VERBOSE/MediaPlayer(824): setVideoSurface                                                                                                                                            
VERBOSE/PVPlayer(2417): setVideoSurface(0x6fd38)                                                                                                                                     
VERBOSE/MediaPlayer(824): prepareAsync                                                                                                                                               
VERBOSE/PVPlayer(2417): prepareAsync                                                                                                                                                 
VERBOSE/PVPlayer(2417):   data source = /test-edition/sample.mp4                                                                                                                     
VERBOSE/PlayerDriver(2417): Send player code: 3                                                                                                                                      
VERBOSE/PlayerDriver(2417): handleSetDataSource                                                                                                                                      
VERBOSE/PlayerDriver(2417): handleSetDataSource- scanning for extension                                                                                                              
ERROR/OsclDirectFileIO(2417): [LargeFileSupport] OsclDirectFileIO::OpenFileOrSharedFd Error = -1                                                                                     
VERBOSE/PlayerDriver(2417): HandleInformationalEvent: 26                                                                                                                             
VERBOSE/PlayerDriver(2417): HandleInformationalEvent: type=26 UNHANDLED                                                                                                              
ERROR/MediaPlayerService(2417): Client::notify In                                                                                                                                    
ERROR/MediaPlayer(824): message received msg=200, ext1=1, ext2=26                                                                                                                    
WARN/MediaPlayer(824): info/warning (1, 26)                                                                                                                                          
ERROR/MediaPlayer(824): callback application                                                                                                                                         
ERROR/MediaPlayer(824): back from callback                                                                                                                                           
VERBOSE/PlayerDriver(2417): CommandCompleted                                                                                                                                         
VERBOSE/PlayerDriver(2417): Completed command PLAYER_SET_DATA_SOURCE status=-4                                                                                                       
ERROR/PlayerDriver(2417): Command PLAYER_SET_DATA_SOURCE completed with an error or info -4                                                                                          
ERROR/MediaPlayerService(2417): Client::notify In                                                                                                                                    
ERROR/MediaPlayer(824): message received msg=100, ext1=-4, ext2=-4                                                                                                                   
ERROR/MediaPlayer(824): error (-4, -4)                                                                                                                                               
ERROR/MediaPlayer(824): callback application                                                                                                                                         
ERROR/MediaPlayer(824): back from callback                                                                                                                                           
VERBOSE/PVPlayer(2417): run_init s=-2147483648, cancelled=0                                                                                                                          
VERBOSE/PlayerDriver(2417): HandleInformationalEvent: 27                                                                                                                             
WARN/PlayerDriver(2417): PVMFInfoErrorHandlingComplete                                                                                                                               
INFO/MediaPlayer(824): Info (1,26)                                                                                                                                                   
ERROR/MediaPlayer(824): Error (-4,-4)                                                                                                                                                
DEBUG/VideoView(824): Error: -4,-4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it:

```
video.setVideoPath("/sdcard/test-edition/sample.3gp");
```

It's look like it is just a URI parser problem, but the VideoView doesn't say anything usefull.

Comment: Actually, if you look at the log, it prints clearly what is the path it sees: `VERBOSE/PVPlayer(2417):   data source = /test-edition/sample.mp4`. Also, as far as I know, it is a bad idea to hard code the path to the sdcard.

Comment: This is just for test purposes.